# Why is mutate_at generating wrong estimates?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset "gf" with a list of variables "v" that I'm manipulating. I first use mutate_at to multiply every variable in "v" by 1000, and then divide it by gf$years. This part of the code works perfectly fine:

```
v = c("Public_Welf_Total_Exp", "Welf_Cash_Total_Exp", "Welf_Cash_Cash_Assist", "Welf_Ins_Total_Exp","Total_Educ_Direct_Exp", "Higher_Ed_Total_Exp",
 "Welf_NEC_Cap_Outlay","Welf_NEC_Direct_Expend", "Welf_NEC_Total_Expend", "Total_Educ_Assist___Sub", "Health_Total_Expend", "Total_Hospital_Total_Exp",
 "Welf_Vend_Pmts_Medical","Hosp_Other_Total_Exp","Unemp_Comp_Total_Exp", "Unemp_Comp_Cash___Sec", "Total_Unemp_Rev", "Hous___Com_Total_Exp", "Hous___Com_Construct", "Total_Expenditure", "Total_IG_Expenditure", "Direct_Expenditure")

gf = gf %>% group_by(FIPS_State, FIPS_County) %>% mutate_at(v, ~ ifelse(. !=0, (. *1000)/gf$years, .)) %>% ungroup()
```

However, directly below this code, I run the following line, which is supposed to divide the variables in "v" by gf$Population, but it calculates the wrong estimates and I have no idea why:

```
gf = gf %>% group_by(FIPS_State, FIPS_County) %>% mutate_at(v, ~ ifelse(. !=0, (. / gf$Population), .)) %>% ungroup()
```

**Can anyone figure out what is wrong with this code? Thanks in advance!**

---

Below is the first 4 rows of "gf" *before* I run both of the mutate_at commands:

```
dput(gf[1:4, ]) 
structure(list(FIPS_State = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), FIPS_County = c(1, 
3, 5, 7), Public_Welf_Total_Exp = c(1396, 5770, 1369, 1020), 
    Welf_Cash_Total_Exp = c(0, 14, 0, 0), Welf_Cash_Cash_Assist = c(0, 
    14, 0, 0), Welf_Ins_Total_Exp = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Total_Educ_Direct_Exp = c(0, 
    1166, 285, 0), Higher_Ed_Total_Exp = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Welf_NEC_Cap_Outlay = c(0, 
    432, 5, 8), Welf_NEC_Direct_Expend = c(1382, 5720, 1260, 
    1020), Welf_NEC_Total_Expend = c(1382, 5723, 1369, 1020), 
    Total_Educ_Assist___Sub = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Health_Total_Expend = c(1166, 
    9386, 777, 394), Total_Hospital_Total_Exp = c(4, 8305, 0, 
    1656), Welf_Vend_Pmts_Medical = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Hosp_Other_Total_Exp = c(4, 
    0, 0, 1656), Unemp_Comp_Total_Exp = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Unemp_Comp_Cash___Sec = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0), Total_Unemp_Rev = c(0, 0, 0, 0), Hous___Com_Total_Exp = c(2106, 
    7364, 5900, 0), Hous___Com_Construct = c(328, 2593, 4732, 
    0), Total_Expenditure = c(267027, 1961849, 210770, 56991), 
    Total_IG_Expenditure = c(25832, 20884, 16994, 4432), Direct_Expenditure = c(241195, 
    1940965, 193776, 52559), Population = c(34730.7272727273, 
    100775.142857143, 25895.6666666667, 16446.8333333333), years = c(21, 
    21, 21, 20)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I'm guessing `gf$Population` is the problem. You already specify `gf %>% ...` at the start so you may just want `Population` instead.

Comment: you are absolutely right - thanks!!

Comment: Is it really? Although you shouldn't use `gf$` in `dplyr` pipes but does it change the calculation here?. I don't even see why you need `group_by` here.

Comment: apparently when I try it without "gf$", it works - not sure why it affects the calculation either. Also, you're right - I don't need group_by for this line! thanks